# Android USB Accessory Support in Android 4.42

Tags: android, usb, microchip, accessory

I have the Android Accessory Development Starter Kit from [Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM240415)
I am running Android 4.4.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S4, however I am unable to get the phone to recognize the USB device when plugged in. The Microchip Accessory Support detection app reads as follows:

```
android.hardware.usb.accessory=true
com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory=false
android.hardware.usb.host=true
android.hardware.wifi.direct=true
android.hardware.bluetooth=ture
```

From what I can tell the Accessory mode is supported in Android 3+, is there some process to enable the Accessory mode ? Any advice on how I would get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [AOA 2.0](https://source.android.com/accessories/aoa2.html) specification